# When I select the adapter settings, then the app is getting squeezed after rotating the touch pad

Tags: c#, wpf

I am working in WPF (with C#) for a touch pad app.

My problem is that when I extract adapter property from the app and then rotate the touch pad at runtime, the app gets squeezed.

If I don't select the adapter, then it works properly even after rotating the touch pad.

I have tried following:

```
this.Height = SystemParameters.MaximizedPrimaryScreenHeight;

WindowState="Maximized" 
WindowStyle="None" 
ResizeMode="NoResize"
```

Comment: put your some sample image...???

Comment: here is the link                              https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B5i8MIHmymZqQnpSc0lRM1k0ZWc/view?usp=sharing                                                                                                        since i want this app in full screen

Comment: some grammar/spelling

Comment: what is this "grammer/spelling"

Comment: try this code:-   SizeToContent="WidthAndHeight"

Comment: thanks but this is Not working

Comment: Grammatical/punctuation and hopefully, tough pad means touch pad

Comment: Grammar and terminology

Comment: Hello clay we are not there to learn english . This is technical sight so its better to suggest technical sol not grammatical error.